# Is there a way to conditionally override the navigation menu for a Shopify Theme in Liquid?

Tags: navigation, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

The original theme has:

````
  {%- liquid
    assign render_menu = false

    if section.settings.main_menu != blank
      assign menu = linklists[section.settings.main_menu]

      if menu.links.size != 0
        assign render_menu = true
      endif
    endif
  -%}```

I'd like to update this so that if the page viewed is using the template page.contractors.liquid, it uses the navigation menu with the handle contractor-menu instead of main-menu.  Either that or display the contractor menu as an additional menu below the header.  Any ideas?


I'm brand new to Liquid and tried this:
````

{%- liquid
assign render_menu = false

if section.settings.main_menu != blank

```
if template == 'page.contractor'
  assign menu = linklists.contractor-menu.links
else
  assign menu = linklists[section.settings.main_menu]
endif
```

if menu.links.size != 0
assign render_menu = true
endif

endif
-%}

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new menu into the section using liquid schema, the same like the current one.
and modify the code like below to use it.

```
{%- liquid
    assign render_menu = false

    if section.settings.main_menu != blank
      if template contains 'contractor'
        assign menu = linklists[section.settings.menuifromsechema] // need id of settings from schem tag
      else
         assign menu = linklists[section.settings.main_menu]
      endif
      if menu.links.size != 0
        assign render_menu = true
      endif
    endif
 -%}
```